# Convert Dictionary values (arrays) into lists

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, key-value

and I'm trying to convert dictionary's values to lists. Therefore, I can extend it to another dictionary's values (which are lists) with same keys.

the dictionary looks like this:

```
Q_VEC_DIC

{'A':array([  2623.8374  ,  -1392.9608  ,    416.2083  ,  -1596.7402  ,],dtype=float32),
'B': array([  1231.1268  ,   -963.2312  ,   1823.7424  ,  -2295.1428  ,],dtype=float32)}
```

I've tried the below, but it returns nothing:

```
ARRAY_TO_LIST=[]
for i in range(len(Q_VEC_DIC)):
    DOC=[]
    DOC.append(list(Q_VEC_DIC.values())[i].tolist)
ARRAY_TO_LIST.append(DOC)
```

How can I to convert values into lists by using loops?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For values do:

```
>>> d={'a':[1,2,3],'b':['a','b','c']}
>>> d.values()
dict_values([[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']])
>>> list(d.values())
[[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

For both keys and values:

```
>>> list(d.items())
[('a', [1, 2, 3]), ('b', ['a', 'b', 'c'])]
```

To answer your question do:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> d = {
    'A': np.array([2623.8374, -1392.9608, 416.2083, -1596.7402,], dtype=np.float32),
    'B': np.array([1231.1268, -963.2312, 1823.7424, -2295.1428,], dtype=np.float32),
}
>>> {k:v.tolist() for k,v in d.items()}
{'A': [2623.83740234375, -1392.9608154296875, 416.20831298828125, -1596.740234375], 'B': [1231.1268310546875, -963.231201171875, 1823.742431640625, -2295.142822265625]}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can extract the values of any dict by calling on values()

```
>>> a = {"a":"1"}
>>> a.values()
0: ['1']
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple and efficient way to convert that dictionary of arrays to a dictionary of lists is to call the `.tolist` method in a dictionary comprehension.

```
import numpy as np

q_vec = {
    'A': np.array([2623.8374, -1392.9608, 416.2083, -1596.7402,], dtype=np.float32),
    'B': np.array([1231.1268, -963.2312, 1823.7424, -2295.1428,], dtype=np.float32),
}

new_vec = {k: v.tolist() for k, v in q_vec.items()}
print(new_vec)
```

**output**

```
{'A': [2623.83740234375, -1392.9608154296875, 416.20831298828125, -1596.740234375], 'B': [1231.1268310546875, -963.231201171875, 1823.742431640625, -2295.142822265625]}
```